# Sorting the values in a listbox when using an expression in the sort tab in Qlikview

Tags: sorting, listbox, expression, qlikview

I want to know if anyone knows how to sort the values in a listbox in Qlikview, when one is forced to have an expression in the sort tab?

I had to use the same expression from the general tab in the sort tab

if(datakilde='Aarlig', Aktivitetsnavn)

Otherwise the listbox didn't show the associated values (from a selected value from another listbox) in the top of the listbox - which aren't very user friendly.

But as a consequence the sorting in alphabetic order is no longer works...

(And I had to have an expression in the general tab, becausecI only need a subset of the loaded data).
(I also tried with the option auto ascending in the state box under the sort tab).

See my sort tab below.

Kind Regards Maria

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions on this, but I think the correct one, would be to create a field in your datamodel, that contains just the values that need in the listbox.

Listboxes are not very good at filtering data. So take your if statement, and put it into the source table:

if(datakilde='Aarlig', Aktivitetsnavn) as Aktivitetsnavn_2

Then you don't have to struggle with filtering data in listboxes and your sorting will be correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip! It totally works now. I even had a problem with the search function in my prevous setup - and now the search function works again !

Comment: herligt, velbekomme ;)

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem while sorting a listbox with values filtered by an expression. I gave up on filtering in listbox and filtered in my load script. After that i was able to sort properly.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for a similar situation I just had was the following:
I've loaded all Items that i needed sorted & filtered out in a separate table, for example:

```
zones:
LOAD * INLINE [
    zone, **zone_order**
    zone A, 1
    zone D, 2
    zone C, 3
    zone B, 4
];
```

I've added my zone in the filter and in the Sort tab, i've chosen to sort by expression: **zone_order**, and that's it!